# Name the product

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

I’m from northwestern Europe.

I have a two-word name, and each word has six letters.

If you take the first two letters of my first name, plus the first two letters of my last name, it spells a new word with the same meaning as my first name.

I also have an embarrassing nickname, which can be abbreviated as WB.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> Stella Artois, the beer from Belgium

Taking the first letters, you get

> Star, which is what Stella means

Your nickname:

> In Britain, Stella Artois apparently has the nickname "Wife Beater"